# Strapi deploy to cpanel

Tags: node.js, deployment, strapi

I am trying to delpoy strapi project to shared host but always have same message
[Error Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAUX9.png)

have anyone uploaded strapi to cpanel give me the right way to deploy it

steps I made :
1-build project
2-made app.js file
3-add db
4-create node app (but also give error on npm install I don't now what the error so uploaded the node_moduls)

any one have any ideas about this problem